# .jnlp Problem ruling in Ubuntu 18.04 and Odroid XU 4

Tags: 14.04, java, bug-reporting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded the latest Oracle Java in Ubuntu 18.04 and also I installed iced tea to run .jnlp. After so long I had some troubles with the start of the .jnlp but I make it run pointing the settings to the directory of Java JRE inside. the iced tea settings but the .jnlp and is almost run but when it will enter I have a crash with this error message:

javafx/beans/property/readonly object property internal error occurred. Please contact customer support

Here are the full logs on pastebin since is running until it crash:

https://pastebin.com/dZWuqhQK

What could be the problem now?